# Laravel Render Partial Form Submit

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-blade

Say I got a blade template (form.blade.php) which has a form that inserts data into inventory.

I would like to share this form on another page which is being called through ajax and loads on a modal on another view (form2.blade.php)

On form2.blade.php

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="inventoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false" style="z-index:9999999">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="inventoryModalHeader"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="inventoryModalBody"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="inventoryModalFooter">
        <button @click="addNewInventory()">Add New Inventory</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue function on form2.blade.php

```
openNewInventoryModal:function(){
                var cur = this;

                axios.get("{{url('/inventory')}}"+"/ajax")
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#inventoryModalHeader").html('New Inventory');
                    $("#inventoryModalBody").html('<form id="addNewInventory">'+response.data+'</form>');
                    $("#inventoryModal").modal("show");
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    swal("Error", "Fatal error, please contact the admin", "error");
                });
            },
```

Problem here is the modal is already in a form, i'm loading ajax in the form. Is there a way where i can render partial a form and submit and close the modal?

Comment: Why didnt you simply create this form as Vue component and render it conditionally?

Comment: because the form.blade.php isn't wrapped in a form tag, it extends a layout which is shared throughout the whole application, am trying to find another way without compromising other modules and in the fastest way because i've just started implementing Vue into the project.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly? You have page with form. From body of this form you want to open modal which contains your form2?

Comment: @piotr okay here's a scenario, i have a product module to insert product, there is a category selection, if category is not added yet the user can click on add category whereby a popup model will generate the create screen for category (this page is available individually, i would like to share this view without making another view, users want to be able to add category on screen for a smoother transaction).